# How to strace adb shell am start myandroidapp

Tags: shell, adb, strace

I need to lean on you for some help on stracing android apps in the sdk emulator

here is my setup

android sdk emulator running android api 4.03
adb shell connected to emulator.

I am able to install an apk usng adb install filename.apk

I am able to run the app using
adb shell
am start -a android.intent.action.Main -n com.akproduction.notepad/com.akproduction.notepad.NoteList

I try to strace using (adb shell)
strace am start -a android.intent.action.Main -n com.akproduction.notepad/com.akproduction.notepad.NoteList
but I get nothing!

how do you trace the runtime behavior of android apps and their installation ?

thanks,

Jose.

p.s. the test app is located here: http://www.appbrain.com/app/ak-notepad/com.akproduction.notepad

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166917/android-how-to-strace-an-app-using-adb-shell-am-start

Answer (score 1):

`am` is a batch file and cannot be used in `strace`.

You need to run it like this:

```
strace -v -fF -tt -s 65535 -o /data/local/tmp/opengl.strace /system/bin/app_process /system/bin com.android.commands.am.Am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n demo.opengl.android/.OpenGLDemo
```

BTW don't use the `strace` statically compiled binary available for download from:

http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/18/android-runtime-strace

It will output nothing.

Instead use the one which comes with the ROM.

Comment: Note that this won't actually trace the application process - it will merely trace the sending of the request to start it.  To trace the application process, you'd have identify it and attach strace to it by PID... and you'd have to have permission to do so, which means being either root or having a shell as the same userid as the application.