# Android: How to strace an app using ADB shell am start

Tags: android, shell, runtime, adb, strace

I need help on stracing Android apps in the SDK emulator.

Here is my setup:

I have an Android SDK emulator running the Android API 4.03 ADB shell connected to emulator.

I am able to install an APK using the ADB install filename.apk

I am able to run the app using the ADB shell `am start -a android.intent.action.Main -n com.akproduction.notepad/com.akproduction.notepad.NoteList`

I try to strace using (ADB shell) `strace am start -a android.intent.action.Main -n com.akproduction.notepad/com.akproduction.notepad.NoteList` but I get nothing!

How do you trace the runtime behavior of Android apps and their installation?

(P.S. The test app is located [here](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ak-notepad/com.akproduction.notepad).

Answer (score 12):

Android apps are actually started by forking the zygote process, so you can trace app initialization by tracing the zygote process and following child processes ('-f'):

```
setenforce 0  # In Android 4.3 and later, if SELinux is enabled, strace will fail with "strace: wait: Permission denied"

set `ps | grep zygote` ; strace -p $2 -f -tt -T -s 500 -o /sdcard/strace.txt
```

Comment: Facing the same issue as mentioned by Aaron. Does anyone know how to handle/resolve this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues using http://benno.id.au/android/strace to trace zygote on Android 5.1.  What version of strace/Android are you having problems with?  Is a stack trace or any other useful info shown by adb logcat when zygote crashes?  Note that zygote may throw and catch SIGSEGV internally to handle null pointers or some garbage collection features, and strace will detect and print this, but that does not necessarily indicate that zygote is actually crashing. Are you just seeing SIGSEGV in the strace output and assuming zygote is crashing, or are you sure zygote is actually crashing?

Answer (score 10):

The "am start" command does not directly run your application; it simply tells Android to do whatever is necessary to, in your example, start a specific activity.

The `strace` command is normally used as in `strace commandname command args` and it launches `commandname` -- easy, but in this Android use case, not helpful. However, strace has a `-p` option which is helpful to you: `strace -p <process id>` will let you start tracing the process with the specified id.

If you type `ps` on your Android system you can locate the process with the name `com.akproduction.notepad` (probably; by default processes are named for their Android package, but it's possible to change that in the manifest). Then you can start stracing it, wherever it happens to be.

If you *need* to catch things early in the process, you'll need to either modify the code to cause it to delay until you're ready to trace it, or you'll at least need to get the process running before you start the activity. The second option there is often as easy as starting the activity, then using the back button, then getting your trace ready, then starting the activity again -- but this is always code-specific to the application.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ugly one-liner hack I used today to solve this issue.  Assuming the program has some known name, just try attaching to the process as soon as it appears.  In this example, I'm interested in all calls to open.

```
while true; do
  while ! ps  | grep -q -i MyProgram; do :; done;
  ps | grep -i MyProgram | while read a b c; do
   strace -e open -f -p $b;
  done;
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner that [grabs the process id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320328) and pipes it to strace right after `am` launches the app. You won't get the first few instructions executed, but it kicks in early enough for my needs.

`` am start -n com.packagename.here\.ActivityName && set `ps | grep com.packagename.here` && strace -p $2 ``

Comment: Based on this oneliner I made another one that should work on Android 9+:
`am start -n com.packagename.here\/.MainActivity && sleep 1 && set \`pidof com.packagename.here\` && strace -f -p $1`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend prior to starting your app start strace on zygote process and follow forks. Zygote process is the main process from which every new process forks in Android, including your app. Then you might want to filter the log based on PIDs you are interested in. Example:

> ps zygote

get the zygote PID, then

> strace -f -p < zygote_PID >

Answer (score 1):

I've found a tricky way to do this and also guarantee that all the syscalls are going to be catch. It can be done even if the app is not debuggable:

- Set the Activity Manager (`am`) to put the app in debug mode with a `-w` option that will halt its execution until it is attached to a debugger
- Start the application manually (you can just click on the screen on its icon or call it with `am start`
- With the application halted, obtain its PID
- With its PID obtained, call strace to trace this process
- Finally, attach the debugger so the execution start.

Here are the steps:

```
adb shell # shell into the device
am set-debug-app -w com.package.name # put app to debug mode
am start com.package.name/com.path.to.MainActivity # start the app
ps -A | grep com.package.name # this will show you the PID
strace -p <PID> > appoutput.txt 2> appstrace.txt 
# strace the program and record its output and strace in txt files
```

Now just attach the debugger and enjoy, you can do it for example in Android Studio or Eclipse. From this point on the execution will begin and you will be able to trace it since the very first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access or the device is running without SELinux enabled, then you can follow the way from Android site:

Set up the device so that you can run strace. You need to be root, disable SELinux, and restart the runtime to remove the seccomp filter that will otherwise prevent strace from running:
adb root
adb shell setenforce 0
adb shell stop
adb shell start

Set up a world-writable directory for strace logs, because strace will be running under the app's uid:
adb shell mkdir -m 777 /data/local/tmp/strace

Choose the process to trace and launch it:
adb shell setprop wrap.com.android.calendar '"logwrapper strace -f -o /data/local/tmp/strace/strace.com.android.calendar.txt"'

Launch the process normally.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/strace#app-strace