# adb: Find PID from the adb shell

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I am trying to get the PID of the process INSIDE adb shell. So, I am doing adb shell which gets me to the android shell. Now, if I were to get the PID using a regular shell I would use

```
adb shell ps | grep android.process.acore | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

OR

```
adb shell ps | grep android.process.acore | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I get the PID (a numeric number - 2nd field of the `ps | grep android.process.acore`) output.

However, if I run the above commands inside android shell(after doing `adb shell`), I get `/system/bin/sh: sed: not found` and `/system/bin/sh: awk: not found` errors respectively. Which means, these commands are not available inside adb shell. However, grep works.

The output of the `ps | grep android.process.acore` inside `adb shell` is:

```
XXX_x21   11826 441   502296 39028 ffffffff 4010ff6c S android.process.acore
```

I am looking for the number 11826.
How can I extract it inside `adb shell`?

Also, please help if there is a direct way to get the PID inside the adb shell.

Regards,
Rumit

Comment: do you have `busybox` installed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if you can get the PID directly however you can try the following

```
set `ps |grep android.process.acore`
echo $2
```

This has the affect of setting the output of the ps command into variables $1, $2, $3 etc. The PID value is in $2

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you for your answer. However, I'm stuck using the command inside adb shell via java runexec(). See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321085/command-with-pipe-and-spaces-does-not-work-with-runtime-exec any help is appreciated. Regards,

Answer (score 20):

Android versions starting with 6.0 already include `pidof` utility:

```
usage: pidof [-s] [-o omitpid[,omitpid...]] [NAME]...

Print the PIDs of all processes with the given names.

-s      single shot, only return one pid.
-o      omit PID(s)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. 
`adb shell pidof com.yourapp`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it seems to work:

```
adb shell "set "ps | grep android.process.media"; kill -9 $2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it seems to work:

1. `adb shell`
2. `ps -A | grep "android.process.acore"`

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell pidof [package name]
```

or

```
adb shell pidof -s [package name]
```

-s option is for single shot, returning only one pid.